# When we use CoreData , UserDefaults, Keychain

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

iOS has more than one local databases like CoreData, Keychain, UserDefault. All 3 databases do the same thing, Saving, Updating, Selecting, etc. Are there any different between them, like security, memory or speed? When using (CoreData, UserDefaults, Keychain) more powerful than others?

Comment: Each have completely different uses. Please read the documentation for each and then update your question with more details about what you need clarified.

Answer (score 6):

Not everything , but in short

- Userdefaults : is used for saving settings data. It's not to be used for temporary data across viewControllers. It's the fastest as it's plist file or a dictionary when it comes to running state of the app
- CoreData : is a relational database used for large data storage , creates models automatically from simple UI and it's a sqlite-based
- Keychain : is the most secure and always used for sensitive data like tokens , passwords etc. But it's also the slowest one as it's a c - wrapper.

Comment: Thanks to answer me . I used them randomly. Now I have some idea about them.

Comment: Core Data is not specifically a database or backed by SQLite. That's just the most common use.

Comment: CoreData is not a database ?? it is even it's UI supports that it's a relational also

Comment: Core Data is for managing object graphs. It support 4 possible persistence models. The SQLite database is just one of the 4 options.

Comment: Core data is an object graph mapper. Just because Core Data is a data persistent doesn't mean that it is a database

Answer (score 1):

[NSCoding/NSKeyed​Archiver vs. Core Data](https://nshipster.com/nscoding/) doesn't directly answer your question. But it's very helpful. Long story short: Core data is a pain in the neck but *when it comes to modeling, querying, traversing and persisting complex object graphs, there is no substitute for Core Data. Core Data is a big hammer, but not every problem is a nail—much less a sufficiently large nail*.

KeyChain is more like a vault. You store small limited information in it e.g. password. You don't store the entire database in it. It acts like a gatekeeper "Can this user open the app? Yes? Ok let's open up our data base and show core data entries..."

UserDefaults are like the last page a user was at. You may store a single custom object, but don't store a big record of it.

Comment: Thanks to answer me . I used them randomly. Now I have some idea about them.

Comment: the userdefault shouldn't be used to store objects at all even if small

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't get you. Can you clarify? I'm asking because I also see: [`set(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414067-set)

Comment: @Honey this used for data like `[1,2,"awea",1.22]` what i meant is that it's not for a custom object